# Parse Lessthan not working when searching date

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud

I have been trying to query between 2 dates dates but it doesn't find anything between the dates. I am getting to the conclusion that might be a bug on CloudCode preventing to make the search correctly.

```
subQuery.lessThanOrEqualTo("endDate", convertDate);
   subQuery.greaterThanOrEqualTo("createdAt", convertDate);
   subQuery.equalTo("type","free");
```